# How to change Leaflet default view?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to change my map center and this is my piece of code , but it doesn't change at all.

please help me...

```
var latlng = L.latLng(34.796607309987564,48.5150837992061);
            this.map = L.map('map-canvas').setView(latlng, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting out with [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com) be sure to check out the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-factory). Here's your solution.

```js
this.map = L.map('map-canvas', {
   center: [
      34.796607309987564,
      48.5150837992061
   ],
   zoom: 2
});
```